# Is there a way to summarize multiple OnClickListener into one function in AndroidStudio?

Tags: java, android-studio, onclicklistener

I got multiple `OnClickListener` for 8 `ImageViews` with the same logic behind. `OnClick Variable-Details` will be shown. I tried to summarize them in a method and tried to add them in the `OnCreate` method with a Loop. But it did not work. Now I have 8 listeners and also 8 `addListener` at `onCreateMethod`.

Is there a more elegant way?

```
 private void addListenerCal1Arrow() {
        ivCalArrow1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!cal1Clicked) {
                    cal1Clicked = true;
                    ivCalArrow1.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow_symbol_up);
                    tvDescription1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    cal1Clicked = false;
                    ivCalArrow1.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow_symbol_down);
                    tvDescription1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

more explanation:
I got an experiment Fragment, where i can add 8 Variables max. Each variable has several textviews and also an ImageView, which holds further information about the variable. when the ImageView is Clicked it shall show the information. I got an container class holding all the widgets of a variable, like the textviews and the imageview and also the description which shall be displayed when its clicked

Comment: Please show us your code.

Comment: `summarize` to which level? use 1 `onClick()` method for the 8 images? refactor the implementation of the logic to make it general for all 8 images? we need to see the code, if they are all the same -as you say-  post content of an onClick() method you have with a brief on what it does

Comment: @JörnBuitink sorry for my poor explanation. Its my first question here.. I added the code of the first OnClickListener. For better comprehension:
I got an experiment Fragment, where i can add 8 Variables max. Each variable has several textviews and also an ImageView, which holds further information about the variable. when the ImageView is Clicked it shall show the information. I got an container class holding all the widgets of a variable, like the textviews and the imageview and also the description which shall be displayed when its clicked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 level to summrize this code

1- use 1 onClick() for all ImageViews: this involves

**1.a implementing** `OnClickListener` and not using `anonymous inner class`
make your activity or fragment `implements OnClickListener` and override `onClick()`

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    //class implementation


    @override
    public void onClick(View view){
    }
}
```

use `this` as OnClickLister for method `setOnClickListener()`:

```
ivCalArrow1.setOnClickListener(this);//this here refers to MyActivity
ivCalArrow2.setOnClickListener(this);//this here refers to MyActivity
//and so on ...
```

**b. recognize** the click source (which ImageView) generated the action)
you will need to compare view id with the 8 ImageViews id and execute proper code based on that:

```
@override
public void onClick(View view){
    if(view.getId() == ivCalArrow1.getId()){
        //do what needed on ivCalArrow1
    }else if(view.getId() == ivCalArrow2.getId()){
        //do what needed on ivCalArrow2
    }
    //and so on ... for 3 4 5 6 7 8
}
```

2- make `onClick()` general to handle the click properly: this involves using arrays instead of single variables named with 1 2 3, like `cal1Clicked` `cal2Clicked` ... or tvDescription1, tvDescription2 ...

**this can be done in several ways, it could be complex to understand or maintain, so try to make it clear**

you might need a Map where `ImageView.getId` as key and some value based on what you need

for example, 
boolean variables `calXClicked` may be you can use a `HashMap`, that the **key** is an identifier for calX and the **value** is `boolean` for the clicked status
from my understanding the identifier for `cal1Clicked` is the imageView itself `ivCalArrow1` so:

declare this class-scope

```
HashMap<int, boolean> calClickedStatus = new HashMap();
```

an at `onCreate()` add this:

```
//assuming all boolean values are false on first create of activity
calClickedStatus.put(ivCalArrow1.getId,false);
calClickedStatus.put(ivCalArrow2.getId,false);
calClickedStatus.put(ivCalArrow3.getId,false); // and so on
```

now at onClick() you will use view.getId as key to lookup other data needed
no need to find what is the source of the click, because you will look it up using the key (view.getId)

```
@override
public void onClick(View view){
    if (!calClickedStatus.get(view.getId())) {
        calClickedStatus.put(view.getId(), true);

        //the view here is actually the clicked ImageView, so just cast it and use it, replace this
        //ivCalArrow1.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow_symbol_up);
        //with this
        ((ImageView)view).setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow_symbol_up);

        //now for this, you may want to use an array of TextView to hold tvDescription1, tvDescription2 ...
        //and make a map to link each tvDescriptionX to the index of licked image
        tvDescription1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        //do same changes here too
        calClickedStatus.put(view.getId(), false);
        ivCalArrow1.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow_symbol_down);
        tvDescription1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

as i mentioned earlier this could be complex and might be hard to explain
and it could be done in may ways, so this is just to guide you on the concept and the rest is up to you

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I think i got the idea behind your approach. I already got the Map you were talking of, i just forgot to mention it. I will let you know if i can successfully implement this. Thanks a lot !

Comment: My most profound thanks, you spared me like 150 lines of code. It works nicely with your approach. The Hashmap you were talking off already existed in my code in the form of a Map, holding all the widgets of a variable(experimentvariable) (layout, textviews, edittext, imageview). Maybe you can help me with another thing i would like to change. As matters stand now, i declared all widgets seperately for each of my experimentvaribles. so i got 8*6 widgets. Is there a way to declare an exemplary and automatically create a new object  every time i add a new experimentvariable?`

Comment: good to hear that, i am not pretty sure i understand what you need, but an identical repeated layout (textviews, buttons ...etc) this mostly can be implemented using `ListView with a custom adapter`, google it and see if it works for you, meanwhile, it's good to accept this answer if it fulfilled your question :)

Comment: sorry that it took me so long to accept your answer! 
i googled the custom adapter list view thing, but it may not suffice for my problem. May i be so bold and just try to explain it to you? As matters stand now i got 8 layouts, each containing a checkbox, 2x textviews, 1x edittext, 1 imageview). Every Layout represents a "Variable", which is added when the user clicks an "Add-Button", and the widgets are filled with information about the chosen variable. My problem is, that i need to declare all 8 layouts with their 6 widgets. Is there a way to create a pattern and use this?

Comment: the listview and adapter looks good, create class for "Variable" with attribures: text1, text2, image...etc, when user click add create object of that class, and add it to the adapter, and it will appear on the list, and you are done...

Answer (score 1):

You can define in your layout for each View the following:

```
android:onClick="myClickFct" 
android:clickable="true"
```

and also in the class which loads the layout the method:

```
public void myClickFct(View view){

       ...

}
```

Comment: lonescu:
Oh my bad. But thank you as well for your idea to solve the problem :)